# How to upload azure custom policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have been working on azure and for Signin process I was uploading the policies.
But I'm getting error while uploading.

> alternativesecurityid is not in the output claims azure

Can anyone guide me in this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Active Directory B2C (Azure AD B2C), social account identities are stored in a userIdentities attribute of a alternativeSecurityIdCollection claim type.
we need to create a JSON representation of the user’s alternativeSecurityId property that can be used in the calls to Azure Active Directory.
Use this claims transformation to generate a alternativeSecurityId ClaimType. It's used by all social identity provider technical profiles, such as Facebook-OAUTH
The following claims transformation receives the user social account ID and the identity provider name.

```
<ClaimsTransformation Id="AddAnotherAlternativeSecurityId" TransformationMethod="AddItemToAlternativeSecurityIdCollection">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="AlternativeSecurityId2" TransformationClaimType="item" />
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="AlternativeSecurityIds" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="AlternativeSecurityIds" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```